# Handle empty cells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to write a condition for when some cells of DataGridView are null or empty.
For example if cells[1] isn't null or empty , a method must be run and ...
I wrote it in some way , but some of them didn't work, and one of them work but its not good solution for my problem.As you now ,empty and null are different in DataGridView.
Additionally , My DataGridView has not been bound to database.
How can i do that in best way?
Regards.

Answer (score 5):

DataGridViewCell object has "Value" method which returns callvalue as object, That value you can convert to string then check this string against null or empty.

```
string val = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string;
if(string.isNullorEmpty(val) ==false)
{
  // your method run.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cell value is a Object. Empty cell Value is null.

DataTable / DataView uses DbNull.Value when Empty.

Strings with Length = 0 are String.Empty

You need verify three options.

Answer (score 0):

if your columns and row layout is fixed then you may call out your function in the cell validating event of the datagrid

```
void dataGridView2_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
           e.Cancel = false;
           if (e.RowIndex == 1 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
               if(string.IsNullorEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString())
                  // method call
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//just replace from Value to FormattedValue like that
string val = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue as string;
if(string.isNullorEmpty(val))
{
  // cell is empty
}
else
{
// cell is not empty
}
```