# Null Value in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I check the null cell value in a DataGridView in C#? I've used DBNull for checking, but it is not working and I'm getting "Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an object" Error.
I'm using VS2010.

Can anybody help me?

DateGridView has the following properties:
Name: dgTelFax
AllowUserToAddRows: True
AllowUserToDeleteRows: True

The code I currently have is:

```
            DataSet objDSTelephone = new DataSet();
            DataTable objDTTelephone = objDSTelephone.Tables.Add();

            string strTelephoneID = "";
            string strTelephone = "";

            int intRecTel = dgTelFax.Rows.Count;
            if (intRecTel > 0)
            {
                //-- Add columns to the data table
                objDTTelephone.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
                objDTTelephone.Columns.Add("telephone", typeof(string));

                for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= intRecTel - 1; i2++)
                {
                    strTelephoneID = (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dgTelFax.Rows[i2].Cells[0].Value)) ? dgTelFax.Rows[i2].Cells[0].Value.ToString() : "";
                    strTelephone = (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dgTelFax.Rows[i2].Cells[2].Value)) ? dgTelFax.Rows[i2].Cells[2].Value.ToString() : "";
                    objDTTelephone.Rows.Add(strTelephoneID, strTelephone);
                }
            }
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155684/handle-empty-cells-in-datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance your dgTelFax does not contain DBNull.Value but simple null. To test this you would write:

```
strTelephoneID = (dgTelFax.Rows[i2].Cells[0].Value ?? string.Empty).ToString();
strTelephone = (dgTelFax.Rows[i2].Cells[2].Value ?? string.Empty).ToString();
```

If type of columns in DataSource is string, it would be sufficient to say:

```
strTelephoneID = (string)dgTelFax.Rows[i2].Cells[0].Value;
strTelephone = (string)dgTelFax.Rows[i2].Cells[2].Value;
```

But the question is - why don't you bind datagrid to objDTTelephone? Then you would not need to transfer data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Before get cell value check the cell value:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgTelFax.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value) {
    strTelephoneID = dgTelFax.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value.Tostring();
}
```